# why select -index array doesn't work, powershell

Tags: arrays, select, powershell

i need to add numbers that don't belong to a linear sequence to retrieve specified indexed folders, i make this attempts :

```
$a =ls | ?{$_.psiscontainer} | sort creationtime
```

Then i try to select only some of the folders(fail):

```
$a | select -Index (100, 101, (103..109))
```

Whit this simplified array i don't have problems:

```
$a | select -Index (103..109)
```

how can i add those numbers?

I try this, forcing the conversion to an array, but the process of conversion fails and i don't know why, if i get the type of the inner members of the array they are already Int32, so i don't understand the error.

```
$a | select -Index @(100, 101, (103..109))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Parameter `-Index` is of type `int[]`. That means that what you pass in as an argument, it has to be an array of numbers.

Imho the simplest way is just to add the arrays like this:

```
0..100 | select -Index (2,3,5 + 20..30 + 50,60)
```

Note that you don't have to do `((2,3,5) + (20..30) + (50,60))`, because the comma operator has higher priority than plus and *interval operator*.

Comment: thanks i didn't knew the add operator for arrays, that is all that i need

Answer (score 2):

For this example, you can get the same result using array slicing:

```
$a[100,101 + 103..109]
```